# Google Maps API Javascript; TypeError a is null

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
var map;
function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.825421, 0.898438),
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListeneer(map, 'click', function(x) {
            ylat.value = x.latLng.lat();
            ylong.value = x.latLng.lng();
        });
    }
        var ylat = document.getElementById('lat');
        var ylong = document.getElementById('loong');

        function addMarker() {
            var lat = ylat.value;
            var loong = ylong.value;

        if(!lat || !loong) return;

        var coordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, loong);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: coordinate
        });
    }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('search'), 'click', addMarker);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

When I run this on Firefox, Firebug tells me "TypeError: a is null" I have looked this up on various websites and on here as well. I don't have the slightest clue on how to fix it. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 issues with this line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('search'), 'click', addMarker);
```

1. <strike>the function `addMarker` is not available in global scope(and not at the time when this line will be executed)</strike>.
2. *(I guess that's the problem here)* assuming the script is placed inside the `<head/>`, the elements inside the `<body/>` are not available yet, `document.getElementById('search')` will be `null`.

Moving the line to the end of initialize should fix both problems.

Additionally, there is a typo:

```
google.maps.event.addListeneer(map, 'click', function(x) {
//__________________________^
```

Comment: I put the   google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('search'), 'click', addMarker);   as the last line and the map renders now. Only problem is the marker is not being displayed. I put:   var addMarker; as global scope and the marker is still not being displayed. What do you suggest?

Comment: did you fix the typo too?

Comment: Yes sir I did. It still doesn't display the marker.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen that there are 2 functions in global scope(addMarker is global too). The lines where you define `ylat` and `ylng` will fail also(see issue #2). Instead of using variables to store the references use getElementById inside to functions to access the input's.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean? "inside to function to accept the input's."